# cannot borrow `self.x` as immutable because `*self` is also borrowed as mutable

Tags: rust, immutability, mutability

First, let the code speak:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Bar;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Qux {
    baz: bool
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {
    bars: Vec<Bar>,
    qux: Qux,
}

impl Foo {
    fn get_qux(&mut self) -> &mut Qux {
        &mut self.qux
    }

    fn run(&mut self) {
        // 1. Fails:
        let mut qux = self.get_qux();

        // 2. Works:
        // let mut qux = &mut Qux { baz: false };

        // 3. Works:
        // let mut qux = &mut self.qux;

        let qux_mut = &mut qux;
        qux_mut.baz = true;

        for bar in &self.bars {
            println!("{:?}", bar);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    let mut foo = Foo { bars: vec!(), qux: Qux { baz: false } };
    foo.run();
}
```

This errors:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self.bars` as immutable because `*self` is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:33:21
   |
22 |         let mut qux = self.get_qux();
   |                       ---- mutable borrow occurs here
...
33 |         for bar in &self.bars {
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
...
36 |     }
   |     - mutable borrow ends here
```

If I uncomment either `2.` or `3.`, why does it compile just fine? The called function in `1.` doesn't do anything drastically different from `2.` or `3.`. So why is it then that `1.` fails to compile?

Although there are [many similar titled questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cannot%20borrow%20as%20immutable), I could not clearly identify this as a dupe (other than the error message being the same), possibly because of my lack of understanding of the ownership/borrowing system in Rust.

Answer (score 12):

In Rust, the compiler stops at the function call boundary when evaluating generic parameters, which includes generic lifetime parameters. In your case 1, you are calling a method:

```
fn get_qux(&mut self) -> &mut Qux {
    &mut self.qux
}
```

This function indicates that *all* of `self` will be borrowed mutably, and that the returned reference will live as long as `self` will. During this time, no other borrows (mutable or not) of self or it's components may be made.

In your second case, you make up a completely new `Qux` that has no attachment to your struct whatsoever. It's not a really great example, because it has very different meaning. **If this case works for you, you should do that**. However, you won't be modifying the same thing as case 1.

In the third case, you avoid the function call. That means that the compiler has a bit more information about what exactly is borrowed. Specifically, it can see that `self.qux` doesn't interact at all with `self.bars`, so there is no error.

You can make your original example work by adding a new scope:

```
fn run(&mut self) {
    {
        let mut qux = self.get_qux();
        let qux_mut = &mut qux;
        qux_mut.baz = true;
    }

    for bar in &self.bars {
        println!("{:?}", bar);
    }
}
```

Here, the artificial scope clearly defines where the mutable borrow ends. Once the borrow is over, other items are allowed to make new borrows.

If you need to modify `qux` inside the loop, then you are required to follow the third pattern:

```
let mut qux = &mut self.qux;

for bar in &self.bars {
    qux.baz = ! qux.baz;
    println!("{:?}", bar);
}
```

Or the simpler:

```
for bar in &self.bars {
    self.qux.baz = ! self.qux.baz;
    println!("{:?}", bar);
}
```

Many times, you can refactor your code to create new structs that have information and encapsulate a nice mutation boundary to make code like this.

Comment: I see. But let's say that the function had some extra logic in it, e.g. it took an id and retrieved `qux` from a vec of Quxes, then I would need to add that logic everywhere. Maybe I need to resort to a macro? ... I know that the `HashMap` and `Vec` types have a `get_mut` method, maybe there's something to learn from their implementation, too. I will have to take another dive.

Comment: @FelixSchlitter without a concrete example (probably another question) it would be hard to give any actionable advice. However, refactoring out a struct with the shared data and methods or accepting a closure have both been useful solutions to this type of problem for me.