# Modifying one attribute of a struct while iterating over another attribute

Tags: iterator, rust, borrow-checker

I have a struct that has 2 `Vec`s. I want to be able to iterate over one while modifying the other one. Here's an example programme:

```
use std::slice;

struct S {
    a: Vec<i32>,
    b: Vec<i32>
}

impl S {
    fn a_iter<'a>(&'a self) -> slice::Iter<i32>  {
        self.a.iter()
    }
    fn a_push(&mut self, val: i32) {
        self.a.push(val);
    }
    fn b_push(&mut self, val: i32) {
        self.b.push(val);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = S { a: Vec::new(), b: Vec::new() };
    s.a_push(1);
    s.a_push(2);
    s.a_push(3);

    for a_val in s.a_iter() {
        s.b_push(a_val*2);
    }
}
```

But there is this compiler error:

```
$ rustc iterexample.rs 
iterexample.rs:28:9: 28:10 error: cannot borrow `s` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
iterexample.rs:28         s.b_push(a_val*2);
                           ^
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
 iterexample.rs:26:5: 29:6 note: expansion site
iterexample.rs:26:18: 26:19 note: previous borrow of `s` occurs here; the immutable borrow prevents subsequent moves or mutable borrows of `s` until the borrow ends
iterexample.rs:26     for a_val in s.a_iter() {
                                   ^
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
iterexample.rs:26:5: 29:6 note: expansion site
iterexample.rs:29:6: 29:6 note: previous borrow ends here
iterexample.rs:26     for a_val in s.a_iter() {
iterexample.rs:27         println!("Looking at {}", a_val);
iterexample.rs:28         s.b_push(a_val*2);
iterexample.rs:29     }
                      ^
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
iterexample.rs:26:5: 29:6 note: expansion site
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I understand what the compiler is complaining about. I have borrowed `self` in the for loop, because I am still looping over it.

Conceptially there should be a way to do this though. I am only modifying `s.b`, and not modifying the thing I'm looping over (`s.a`). Is there anyway to write my programme to demostrate this separation, and allow this sort of programme to compile?

This is a simplified example of a larger programme, so I need to keep the general structure the same (a struct that has some things, one of which will be iterated over, and another that will be updated).

Comment: I might be very wrong, don't take my word for this, it's just a guess, but I think that the conceptual reason why you can't do this is that if pushing to `s.b` causes `s` to be relocated in memory, then the reference to `s.a` will be invalidated. You could always use `s.a.clone().iter()` instead of `s.a.iter()` to fix this though.

Comment: @Adrian using `s.a.iter` and `s.b.push` would actually work fine. I suspect that @Rory wants to keep the fields private in their non-simplified code (or `a_iter` and `b_push` might actually be more complicated, not just simple wrappers around `Vec` methods).

Comment: @Adrian where your reasoning doesn't hold is that pushing to `s.b` will not relocate `s`, but will relocate the internal piece of memory owned by `s.b` and specifically pointed to by its private `ptr` field (see implementation of `Vec`).

Comment: @fjh You're right. I want to keep the things private. I want these functions be "abstractions" over more complicated things.

Comment: @Adrian Tried that, and get a new error in `a_iter` about "borrorwed value does not live long enough". Also get the same error as before "cannot borrow `s` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have "solved" this problem using macros. If I use the following code, it works:

```
use std::slice;

struct S {
    a: Vec<i32>,
    b: Vec<i32>
}

impl S {
    fn a_push(&mut self, val: i32) {
        self.a.push(val);
    }
}

macro_rules! a_iter {
    ($x: expr) => {
        { $x.a.iter() }
    }
}

macro_rules! b_push {
    ($x: expr, $val: expr) => {
        $x.b.push($val);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = S { a: Vec::new(), b: Vec::new() };
    s.a_push(1);
    s.a_push(2);
    s.a_push(3);

    let iter = a_iter!(s);

    for a_val in iter {
        println!("Looking at {}", a_val);
        b_push!(s, a_val*2);
    }
}
```

Here, I have moved the `a_iter` and `b_push` code into a macro. When the code is compiled, the macro will be expanded and it's as if we're not using an abstraction function(s). However for writing the code, that functionality is abstracted away.

I'm not sure if they is a good or bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

You can remove the error if you use `s.a.it` instead of `s.a_iter()`.
Your current solution doesn't work because the returned iterator from `s.a_iter()` keep a reference of `s` which have the same lifetime of `s` itself, and so until that reference is alive you cannot borrow as mutable something inside `s`. Specifically this happens because:

> the compiler stops at the function call boundary when evaluating
>   generic parameters

(the lifetime in your case)

Here there's a good answer which contains a complete explanation of a very similar problem:
[cannot borrow `self.x` as immutable because `*self` is also borrowed as mutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31093841/cannot-borrow-self-x-as-immutable-because-self-is-also-borrowed-as-mutable)

**Edit**

A possible solution could be to bring the operation inside `S` instead of bring out the iterator from `S`. You can define in `S` a method like this:

```
fn foreach_in_a_push_to_b<F>(&mut self, func: F) where F : Fn(&i32) -> i32 {
    for a_val in self.a.iter() {
        self.b.push(func(a_val));
    }
}
```

and then

```
s.foreach_in_a_push_to_b(|&x| x * 2);
```

Comment: Yes that would probably solve *this* example. However I want to keep this "API" the same, namely, I need a function that that I can use to iterate over. I don't want to "reach inside" the struct.

Comment: @Rory Would it make sense to expose the iterate-and-push logic as a method on `S`? In there, you could directly access `a` and `b` without making them public. I obviously can't tell if that makes sense without knowing the specifics.

Comment: @fjh at the moment that is the only solution I can think of, but maybe is not enough yet for Rory. I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: *(after edit)* That could work. The problem is that I want to swap out `a` & `b` from `Vec` (they're `HashMap`s in Real Version), with more complicated datastructres which will have more complicated logic for `push` and `iter`...

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental problem is that the borrow checker doesn't have enough information to prove your code is safe; it stops at function boundaries.  You can get around this by writing a method that splits the reference such that the compiler *does* have the information it needs:

```rust
struct S {
    a: Vec<i32>,
    b: Vec<i32>
}

impl S {
    fn a_push(&mut self, val: i32) {
        self.a.push(val);
    }
    fn split_a_mut_b<'a>(&'a mut self) -> (&'a Vec<i32>, &'a mut Vec<i32>) {
        (&self.a, &mut self.b)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = S { a: Vec::new(), b: Vec::new() };
    s.a_push(1);
    s.a_push(2);
    s.a_push(3);

    let (a, b) = s.split_a_mut_b();

    for a_val in a.iter() {
        b.push(a_val*2);
    }
}
```

They key here is that within `split_a_mut_b`, the compiler can prove the two borrows do not overlap.  Another pattern you can use, which lets you retain more of the original API, is to temporarily disassemble the value into mutable and immutable parts:

```
use std::slice;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct S {
    a: Vec<i32>,
    b: Vec<i32>
}

impl S {
    fn a_iter(&self) -> slice::Iter<i32>  {
        self.a.iter()
    }
    fn a_push(&mut self, val: i32) {
        self.a.push(val);
    }
    fn b_push(&mut self, val: i32) {
        self.b.push(val);
    }
    fn split_a_mut_b<F, R>(&mut self, f: F) -> R
    where F: FnOnce(&Self, &mut Self) -> R {
        use std::mem::swap;

        // Break off the mutable part(s) (or the immutable parts if there
        // are less of those).
        let mut temp = S { a: vec![], b: vec![] };
        swap(&mut self.b, &mut temp.b);

        // Call the closure.
        let result = f(self, &mut temp);

        // Glue the value back together.
        swap(&mut self.b, &mut temp.b);

        result
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = S { a: Vec::new(), b: Vec::new() };
    s.a_push(1);
    s.a_push(2);
    s.a_push(3);

    s.split_a_mut_b(|imm, muta| {
        for a_val in imm.a_iter() {
            muta.b_push(a_val*2);
        }
    });

    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

This is *not* terribly inefficient; this method introduces *absolutely no heap activity*; we're just shuffling pointers around.

Answer (score 0):

With raw pointers, you can alias the struct into a second variable -- Rust will consider them as two different variables and let you borrow the immutable part without complaining.

```
let s_alias = &s as *const S;
let a_iter = unsafe { (*s_alias).a_iter() };

for a_val in a_iter {
    s.b_push(a_val*2);
}
```

[Playground](http://is.gd/nK3E5C)

I welcome a second opinion on this, but I don't see how it could cause any memory safety issue, in this example at least.