# Iterating over a vector of mutable references to trait objects

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a `struct` that holds mutable references to trait objects:

```
trait Task {
    fn do_it(&mut self);
}

struct Worker<'a> {
    tasks: Vec<&'a mut Task>,
}
```

In a method of `Worker`, I want to iterate over the tasks and call their `do_it`:

```
impl<'a> Worker<'a> {
    pub fn work(&mut self) {
        for task in self.tasks.iter() {
            self.work_one(*task);
        }
    }

    fn work_one(&self, task: &mut Task) {
        task.do_it();
    }
}
```

Sadly, the borrow checker does not let me do it:

```
error[E0389]: cannot borrow data mutably in a `&` reference
  --> src/main.rs:12:27
   |
12 |             self.work_one(*task);
   |                           ^^^^^ assignment into an immutable reference
```

I cannot make `Worker` generic because I want it to hold tasks of many types. I also need tasks to be mutable. How do I do it in Rust?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are calling `tasks.iter()` which produces immutable references to the elements of `Vec`. You actually get back `&&mut Task`, an immutable reference to a mutable one (that is why the Rust compiler is complaining).

To solve this, call `tasks.iter_mut()` to get an iterator of mutable references.

The second problem is calling defining `work_one` as a method. You already borrow a mutable reference from `self` when iterating, so you cannot get another borrow.

Working example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1568fc5c1e31e9fc85266874fae60260&version=undefined)):

```
trait Task {
    fn do_it(&mut self);
}

struct Worker<'a> {
    tasks: Vec<&'a mut Task>,
}

impl<'a> Worker<'a> {
    pub fn work(&mut self) {
        for task in self.tasks.iter_mut() {
            Worker::work_one(*task);
        }
    }

    fn work_one(task: &mut Task) {
        task.do_it();
    }
}
```

To still have access to `self` in `work_one` this workaround can be used. This basically just swaps the two vectors so you do not actually borrow `self` when iterating and then swapping it back. This is ugly, there may be a better pattern here, maybe someone else will suggest something better.

```
pub fn work(&mut self) {
    let mut tasks = vec![];
    mem::swap(&mut tasks, &mut self.tasks);
    for task in tasks.iter_mut() {
        self.work_one(*task);
    }
    mem::swap(&mut tasks, &mut self.tasks);
}
```

A nicer alternative suggested by @Veedrac:

```
fn work(&mut self) {
    let mut tasks = mem::replace(&mut self.tasks, Vec::new());
    for task in &mut tasks {
        self.work_one(*task);
    }
    self.tasks = tasks;
}
```

Comment: "immutable reference to a mutable one" Aaah, this is a piece I was missing. And regarding references to self: this means that if I would need to do any change of state of self, I need to do it withing the body of the `for` loop. Do I get it right?

Comment: @Tomo Updated the answer, not really an ideal solution. Hope someone else can suggest something better.

Comment: Yes, this looks ugly. :)

Comment: @Tomo Unless you're more specific about the problem, you probably can't do much better. If you lend out `self` mutably, you're giving permission for unrestricted modifications. That said, [it can be made prettier than two `swap`s](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=987c95c143faf9115e40b8dca3eea034&version=stable&backtrace=0).

Comment: @Veedrac I don't know if I need to modify `Worker`'s state. I asked out of curiosity. Thank you for the `mem::replace` trick, it's good to have it in my toolbox.

Comment: It's been 4 years, but never the less...
I was struggling with the same problem recently and my solution ended up being the `RefCell`. So, for this example it would be like this: make `Worker.tasks` a `RefCell<Vec<Task>>` and change loop to `for task in self.tasks.borrow_mut().iter_mut() { ... }`.
I wonder is it a good and ideomatic solution or just an ugly hack?

Answer (score 6):

You need to have a mutable reference to each item. `iter` returns immutable references. And a immutable reference to a mutable variable is not itself mutable. Use `iter_mut` or `for task in &mut self.tasks` instead.

Then, the *easiest* thing to do is to inline `work_one` into `work`:

```
pub fn work(&mut self) {
    for task in self.tasks.iter_mut() {
        task.do_it()
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, splitting this into two functions is quite painful. You have to guarantee that calling `self.work_one` will not modify `self.tasks`. Rust doesn't track these things across function boundaries, so you need to split out all the other member variables and pass them separately to a function.

See also:

- [Why does refactoring by extracting a method trigger a borrow checker error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57017747/155423)
- [cannot borrow `self.x` as immutable because `*self` is also borrowed as mutable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31093841/155423)
- [Why are borrows of struct members allowed in &mut self, but not of self to immutable methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42879098/155423)