# Why does refactoring by extracting a method trigger a borrow checker error?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

The architecture of my networking application can be stripped down to the following:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

/// Represents remote user. Usually has fields,
/// but we omit them for the sake of example.
struct User;

impl User {
    /// Send data to remote user.
    fn send(&mut self, data: &str) {
        println!("Sending data to user: \"{}\"", data);
    }
}

/// A service that handles user data.
/// Usually has non-trivial internal state, but we omit it here.
struct UserHandler {
    users: HashMap<i32, User>,  // Maps user id to User objects.
    counter: i32  // Represents internal state
}

impl UserHandler {
    fn handle_data(&mut self, user_id: i32, data: &str) {
        if let Some(user) = self.users.get_mut(&user_id) {
            user.send("Message received!");
            self.counter += 1;
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Initialize UserHandler:
    let mut users = HashMap::new();
    users.insert(1, User{});
    let mut handler = UserHandler{users, counter: 0};

    // Pretend we got message from network:
    let user_id = 1;
    let user_message = "Hello, world!";
    handler.handle_data(user_id, &user_message);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b59dc2d6639ddf66c1ac2fe42eef3c54)

This works OK. I would like to make a separate method in `UserHandler` that handles user input when we have already established that user with given id exists. So it becomes:

```rust
impl UserHandler {
    fn handle_data(&mut self, user_id: i32, data: &str) {
        if let Some(user) = self.users.get_mut(&user_id) {
            self.handle_user_data(user, data);
        }
    }

    fn handle_user_data(&mut self, user: &mut User, data: &str) {
        user.send("Message received!");
        self.counter += 1;
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e540791979a7130cd0af7b93ca063c5f)

All of a sudden, it doesn't compile!

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:24:13
   |
23 |         if let Some(user) = self.users.get_mut(&user_id) {
   |                             ---------- first mutable borrow occurs here
24 |             self.handle_user_data(user, data);
   |             ^^^^                  ---- first borrow later used here
   |             |
   |             second mutable borrow occurs here
```

At first glance, the error is pretty obvious: you can not have a mutable reference to `self` and to an attribute of `self` - it is like having two mutable references to `self`. But then, what the heck, I **do** have two mutable references like this in the original code!

1. Why does this simple refactoring trigger borrow checker error?
2. How do I work around it and decompose `UserHandler::handle_data` method like this?

If you wonder why I want such refactoring, consider a case when there are multiple types of messages that user could send, all need to be handled differently, but there is a common part: having to know which `User` object sent this message.

Comment: Thank you. However, I do have to borrow it, and borrow as mutable, since the real code modifies UserHandler state in message handlers.

Comment: Edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The compiler is right to prevent you from borrowing the `HashMap` twice. Suppose in `handle_user_data()` you also tried to borrow `self.users`. You would break the rules of borrowing in Rust because you already have a mutable borrow on it and you can only have one.

Since you can't borrow `self` twice for your `handle_user_data()`, I will propose a solution. I don't know if it's the best, but it works without unsafe and without overhead (I think).

The idea is to use an intermediate struct that will borrow the other fields of `self`:

```rust
impl UserHandler {
    fn handle_data(&mut self, user_id: i32, data: &str) {
        if let Some(user) = self.users.get_mut(&user_id) {
            Middle::new(&mut self.counter).handle_user_data(user, data);
        }
    }
}

struct Middle<'a> {
    counter: &'a mut i32,
}

impl<'a> Middle<'a> {
    fn new(counter: &'a mut i32) -> Self {
        Self {
            counter
        }
    }

    fn handle_user_data(&mut self, user: &mut User, data: &str) {
        user.send("Message received!");
        *self.counter += 1;
    }
}
```

This way, the compiler knows we can't borrow `users` twice.

If you have only one or two things to borrow, a quick solution is to have an associated function that takes them as parameters:

```
impl UserHandler {
    fn handle_user_data(user: &mut User, data: &str, counter: &mut i32) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

We can improve this design:

```rust
struct UserHandler {
    users: HashMap<i32, User>, // Maps user id to User objects.
    middle: Middle,              // Represents internal state
}

impl UserHandler {
    fn handle_data(&mut self, user_id: i32, data: &str) {
        if let Some(user) = self.users.get_mut(&user_id) {
            self.middle.handle_user_data(user, data);
        }
    }
}

struct Middle {
    counter: i32,
}

impl Middle {
    fn new(counter: i32) -> Self {
        Self {
            counter
        }
    }

    fn handle_user_data(&mut self, user: &mut User, data: &str) {
        user.send("Message received!");
        self.counter += 1;
    }
}
```

Now we are sure we don't have overhead and the syntax is much cleaner.

Further information can be found in Niko Matsakis' blog post [After NLL: Interprocedural conflicts](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2018/11/01/after-nll-interprocedural-conflicts/). Mapping this answer to the blog post:

- solution #1 -> "View structs as a general, but extreme solution" section
- solution #2 -> "Free variables as a general, but extreme solution" section (here expressed as an associated function)
- solution #3 -> "Factoring as a possible fix" section

Comment: Or basically have a method `fn handle_user_date(user: &mut User, data: &str, counter: &mut i32)`

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Yes but I tried to explain the general method because if there are 42 fields to borrow it's gonna be painful

Comment: Thanks, your explanation of the error reason is enlightening. Basically borrow checker prevents a whole class of bugs like inserting into `self.users` in one of the handler methods, which invalidates the `User` reference!

Answer (score 4):

When calling `self.handle_user_data`, you're taking the whole `self` mutably while still having a mutable borrowed `user` object, which Borrow Checker doesn't like. You can't have two mutable borrows as the same time.

One method to circumvent this is not take whole `self` mutably but take the `counter` mutably:

```
impl UserHandler {
    fn handle_data(&mut self, user_id: i32, data: &str) {
        if let Some(user) = self.users.get_mut(&user_id) {
            handle_user_data(user, data, &mut self.counter);
        }
    }
}

fn handle_user_data(user: &mut User, data: &str, counter: &mut i32) {
    user.send(data);
    *counter += 1;
}
```

Comment: Like this idea.