# Rust lang stateful machine api design

Tags: design-patterns, rust

i'm learning rust, and i have a problem with the design of some sort of stateful machine
a minimal example would be something like:

```
struct Bar {
    x: u32
}

struct Foo {
    v: Vec<Bar>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn foo(&mut self, x: usize) {
        self.bar(&self.v[x]);
    }

    fn bar(&mut self, b: &Bar) {
        self.v.push(Bar{x: b.x});
    }
}
```

the problem is obviusly the compiler error: "cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable",
at the line: "self.bar(&self.v[x])"
i pretty much understand the error and i'm lookin for some ways to solve the problem, as i know for a fact that i'm not
mutating the vector "v", i already know the RefCell method, and i'm looking far all the possibilities just for better understanding of rust.

I'm open with any ideas, thanks everyone!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does refactoring by extracting a method trigger a borrow checker error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57017747/why-does-refactoring-by-extracting-a-method-trigger-a-borrow-checker-error)