# Cannot use iterator from one method in another because the "borrow might be used when that temporary is dropped"

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a struct with two methods. The first method returns an iterator over some field. The second method calls the first one and subsequently tries to modify that field ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c674a1d88bb4de1f7d29d4c809f81d10)):

```
struct Container {
    vec: Vec<f64>,
}

impl Container {
    fn large_positions<'a>(&'a self) -> impl Iterator<Item = usize> + 'a {
        self.vec
            .iter()
            .enumerate()
            .filter_map(|(i, &f)| if f > 3.14 { Some(i) } else { None })
    }

    fn negate_first_large_entry(&mut self) {
        if let Some(i) = self.large_positions().next() {
            self.vec[i] *= -1.0;
        }
    }
}
```

The borrow checker complains:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self.vec` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/lib.rs:15:13
   |
14 |         if let Some(i) = self.large_positions().next() {
   |                          ----------------------
   |                          |
   |                          immutable borrow occurs here
   |                          a temporary with access to the immutable borrow is created here ...
15 |             self.vec[i] *= -1.0;
   |             ^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
16 |         }
17 |     }
   |     - ... and the immutable borrow might be used here, when that temporary is dropped and runs the destructor for type `impl Iterator`
```

If I manually inline `large_positions`, the code compiles so the destructor thing is not a real issue.

Why does the borrow checker know that there is no conflict in the inlined version?
And how can I explain this to the borrow checker in the non-inlined version?

**Update:**
The following slightly different version of the second function exhibits the same behavior: ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=eb4ca4aa26f9a7f2e42db49740304020))

```
fn negate_first_large_entry_below_100(&mut self) {
    for i in self.large_positions() {
        if self.vec[i] < 100.0 {
            self.vec[i] *= -1.0;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Here the `return`  statement causes the borrow checker to understand that the borrow of `self.vec` can be released as soon as the `if` branch is entered. But again this only works if `large_positions` is inlined.

Ideally I would like to modify the signature of `large_positions` in such a way that the borrow checker is still able to perform this clever "early releasing".

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Why does refactoring by extracting a method trigger a borrow checker error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57017747/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Specifically, what if `self.vec[i] *= -1.0` caused the vector to reallocate, invalidating any references? Then using the  iterator would cause memory unsafety. The compiler is preventing you from introducing vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Shepmaster Isn't that question centered about borrowing two distinct fields of `self`? Here there is only one field.

Comment: As a practical solution, you can do `let v = self.large_positions().next();` to show that the iterator is no longer needed after advancing it once.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks. In the original code this "practical solution" would be less elegant than here, so I'm still interested in understanding the underlying issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can extrat the iterator into a variable that you can later drop in order to get a `&mut` afterwards:

```rust
    fn negate_first_large_entry(&mut self) {
        let mut iter = self.large_positions();
        if let Some(i) = iter.next() {
            drop(iter);
            self.vec[i] *= -1.0;
        }
    }
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a05fa9452fb03a705a131c4ea8713d2e)

For the second method you just need to use a while loop instead of a for loop to perform the same trick:

```rust
    fn negate_first_large_entry_below_100(&mut self) {
        let mut iter = self.large_positions();
        while let Some(i) = iter.next() {
            if self.vec[i] < 100.0 {
                drop(iter);
                self.vec[i] *= -1.0;
                return;
            }  
        }
    }
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1d2444fca19189fb07a1930c286eb0c7)

Comment: Very interesting. I've never seen `drop` used to help the borrow-checker. Do you think this could also work in `negate_first_large_entry_below_100` (see question update)?

Comment: @wonce of course it would. Check update :)

Answer (score 0):

*(I believe to have now gained a superficial understanding of the underlying problem, so I will formulate this as an answer. Comments are welcome.)*

As the error message hints and the answer by Netwave demonstrates, the issue is related to dropping `iter`. Upon dropping `iter`, the borrow of `self.vec` is freed. If this happens before `self.vec` is modified, then the code borrow-checks successfully.

In the non-inlined version, the drop of `iter` happens when `iter` goes out of scope. The compiler is not able to move this forward, because it is not aware whether `iter` has any user-defined `Drop` implementation.

In contrast, in the manually inlined version of the code, the compile is able to perform this drop immediately after the last time `iter` is used. I presume this optimization is possible because the compiler knows here that no custom code is run upon dropping `iter` (not sure how I could verify this).

A proper solution to the problem would thus be to extend the return type of `large_positions`, indicating that the returned value may be dropped before it leaves scope. If I understand [this proposal](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/fixing-the-drop-trait-bound/9458) correctly, this is currently impossible because such a "TrivialDrop" trait does not exist in Rust.